# How can I get the MAC address of my computer?

Tags: java, mac-address

I want to get my MAC address. I used following code to do that. But I get output as `FF`. It is not my mac address. `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:ff` is my mac address.

```
public String getMacAddress() {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networks = null;
    String macaddress=null;
    try {
        networks = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    NetworkInterface inter;
    while (networks.hasMoreElements()) {
        inter = networks.nextElement();
        byte[] mac = null;
        try {
            mac = inter.getHardwareAddress();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (mac != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                macaddress=String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    return macaddress;
}
```

How can I get my MAC address?

Comment: In your loop to keep over writing the macaddress so it is only the last value. Did you intend to use += ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah i tried to use `+=` but got an error that line.please can u mention how can i solve this

Comment: To use `+=`, you need in initial value e.g. `String macaddress = "";`

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
package com.mkyong;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class App{

public static void main(String[] args){

InetAddress ip;
try {

    ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

    NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

    byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

    System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

   } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

   }catch (SocketException e){

    e.printStackTrace();

  }

 }
}
```

Output:

*Current IP address : 192.168.1.22
Current MAC address : 00-26-B9-9B-61-BF*

Comment: Don't forget to credit the [source](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems that I see.

Firstly you are reassigning the value of `macaddress`. Meaning there will always be just the last byte from `mac`. The second problem is that you are iterating over all the interfaces your machine has, so even if you changed

```
macaddress = String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
macaddress += String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
```

to append, rather than assign, you would get a string with all the MAC addresses your machine has. Also you would have to initialize `macaddress` to an empty string (since you cannot append to `null`).

Since you are iterating over all interfaces, how about returning a `Collection` of rather than a single `String`? Also using `StringBuilder` may be more appropriate.

```
public List<String> getMacAddress() { // Change return type from String to List<String>
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networks = null;
    try {
        networks = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    NetworkInterface inter;
    List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<>(); // Create list to store all MAC addresses
    while (networks.hasMoreElements()) {
        inter = networks.nextElement();
        byte[] mac = null;
        try {
            mac = inter.getHardwareAddress();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (mac != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Rather than appending with += use a String builder
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "")); // Use append on the string builder
            }
            addresses.add(sb.toString()); // Add MAC address to the Collection
        }
    }
    return addresses; // Return collection rather than one String
}
```